# Having a String or int with a binding to a Property

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to make a programm in JavaFX where I need to manage a movie library. I have a tableview that is filled by an observable list. Then I made bindings between the Properties and the Textboxes or Labels next to the tableview. Now the problem is, I have also pictures that are related to the movies, like cinema posters. and at the moment I just use a hardcoded one:

```
imgPoster = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/images/posters/" + 5 + ".jpg"));
```

In the datafile there is one column with the ID of the movie and the same number is also the picture for it. So I need to replace that "5" in the sample code with a binding or so that it actively changes the picture as soon as I click on a row in the tableview.

How do I do that?

edit:

After the first comment i did that:

```
imgOscars = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/images/oscar/Oscar-logo.png"));
    oscars = new ImageView(imgOscars);
    oscars.setPreserveRatio(true);
    oscars.setFitHeight(45);
```

but question stays

Comment: Not possible. Consider `Image` immutable for this purpose. However you could replace the `Image` displayed in a `ImageView`...

Comment: i changed it ... but how can i do that now ?

Answer (score 0):

Either add a listener to the selected item property in the table (I am just guessing at the model you are using for the table):

```
TableView<Movie> table = ... ;

table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelectedMovie, newSelectedMovie) -> {
    if (newSelectedMovie == null) {
        oscars.setImage(null);
    } else {
        // get image from new selection
        Image image =  new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/images/oscar/"+newSelectedMoviegetId()+".png")); 
        oscars.setImage(image);
    }
});
```

or use a binding:

```
oscars.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) {
        return null ;
    } else {
        Movie selected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        return  new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../resources/images/oscar/"+selected.getId()+".png")); ; 
    }, 
    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```